# reason for a column having more than one index, MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to understand why in one of my table there are two index assigned to one column. I've tried searching it however even though there are lot of resources explaining index on multiple columns I cannot seem to find information on one single column having more than one index.

When I run

```
show index from table_name
```

it gives me:

```
 Table    Non_unique      Key_name      Seq_in_index  Column_name Collation  Cardinality  Index_type
table_name  0            PRIMARY             1           id          A          4863        BTREE       
table_name  0     serial_number_1            1      serial_number    A          4863        BTREE       
table_name  0               key3             1         imei          A          4863        BTREE   
table_name  1     serial_number_2            1       serial_number   A          4863        BTREE       
table_name  1              key_2             1        partner_id     A            6         BTREE       
table_name  1              key               1        location       A          4863        BTREE
```

As you can see under Key_name there are serial_number_1, serial_number_2 which are assigned to same column_name "serial_number". What is the reason for this, does it increase efficiency if yes, why?

**ANSWER** it has been marked duplicated by Bill and that post seems to solve my curiosity.

Comment: Another reason:  In some situations, a `FOREIGN KEY` will generate an extra index.  But, again, you don't need both.

Answer (score 0):

`serial_number_1` appears to be a unique index on the column `serial_number`, while `serial_number_2` is a non unique index on that same column.  While these two indices can coexist with each other, the existence of the unique index means that the `serial_number` column is already unique.  Hence, the `serial_number_2` index is redundant, and you should be safe to delete it.